# "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0” not recognized in Windows 10

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, windows-10

**Background**

I'm developing a Windows Form application which connects to a Microsoft Access database.

This is a sample code that I use in the development:

```
try
{
    string AccessFilePath = @"\.myDataBase.mdb"; // Path of the Access database.
    string sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE IdTable = 5;";
    string connstr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + AccessFilePath;
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connstr);
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = sqlStatement;
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox("Error: " + ex.Message);
}
```

The following list describes the environment of my development:

- Visual Studio 2015 Community
- Solution created in Framework .NET 4.0
- Operating system: Windows 10 Pro - 64 bits.
- This development must work on Windows XP, Windows 7 and upper versions.

I had already installed:

- [2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734)
- [Microsoft .NET 4.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=17851) *(in Windows XP and other computers who needs it)*

**Issues**

In my PC *which has Windows 10 Pro OS*, I search in the *C:/* Hard Disk and I found that **ACEOLEDB.DLL** is already installed in the following locations:

*This is **before** install the Data Connectivity Components:*

```
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\VFS\ProgramFilesCommonX86\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE16
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE15
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE14
```

*Click to enlarge the image:*

[image: Previous to install Data Connectivity Components]

When I installed the Data Connectivity Components in my PC, the **ACEOLEDB.DLL** is located at:

```
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\VFS\ProgramFilesCommonX86\Microsoft Shared
```

I really don't know why *even after install Data Connectivity Components* I'm still getting this error:

> "The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine"

---

**Questions**

- How Data Connectivity Components are handled by the OS?
- How can validate correctly if OS has the Data Connectivity Components installed?

Comment: Platform Target: x86?

Comment: @LarsTech is in _Any CPU_

Comment: @LarsTech I can't. The only option available is _Any CPU_

Comment: Are you looking in the right place?  Properties -> Build -> Platform Target

Comment: @LarsTech yes, this is a [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gWgcx.png)

Comment: Try Platform Target.  A little lower.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121269/discussion-between-mauricio-and-larstech).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After change the *Platform Target* to **x86** as user LarsTech suggested in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39020305/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-not-recognized-in-windows-10#comment65394493_39020305), in the end user machines *which has Windows 7 OS and no Office suite installed*. It worked correctly.

I though that this change would be enough, but, for some unknown reason, in my PC, that wasn't.

So, I have to research again and I found a similar problem [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-access/how-to-install-or-register-or-setup-aceodbcdll-for/f853f1a6-050e-43d5-8391-2f9dbe651751?auth=1).

The workaround *in this particular situation* is install:

**[Microsoft Access 2010 Runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10910)**

*In my case*, the following **ACEOLEDB.DLL** entries were created:

```
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE12
- C:\Windows\Installer\$PatchCache$\Managed\00004109C10000000000000000F01FEC\14.0.4763
```

*I think that the last entry* was created by the 2010 Runtime installation.